# solr faceted search - parameter prefix is case sensitive?

Tags: solr

I am trying to implement a suggest function using solr (1.4).
I am using the following configuration in schema.xml

```
<field name="suggest" type="text_auto" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<fieldType name="text_auto" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and copying some stuff into it.

```
<copyField source="otca_entity_GL_parents_str" dest="suggest"/>
<copyField source="facet_otca_entity_PG" dest="suggest"/>
```

Now I search for:

> &facet=true&facet.field=suggest&facet.mincount=1&facet.prefix=**Ger**

I get no results, but with:

> &facet=true&facet.field=suggest&facet.mincount=1&facet.prefix=**ger**

I get results.

Any idea why this is happening?

My goal is to have a result in the case I store it "Germany", independent if you prefix is with ger or Ger.

Comment: How facet.prefix could limit your results? According yo official documentation - it shouldn't limit result list.
Second - faceting a text field it's usually a bad idea, since it contains a lot of trash. What is the purpose of doing that?

Comment: Sure faceting is limiting your results, ist like a filter nothing else imho. I my case i fill a field "suggest" with data e.g. Germany. Now i want to get Germany when i prefix facet with "ger" or "Ger" but only "ger" is giving some results. This is becouse if added the LowerCaseFilterFactory. My goal it to have matches for a suggester independent from the case.

Comment: Once again. facet.prefix doesn't limit your result list

"facet.prefix

Limits the terms on which to facet to those starting with the given string prefix. Note that unlike fq, this does not change the search results -- it merely reduces the facet values returned to those beginning with the specified prefix."

Comment: Im my case the search results are the factes:-)